# Can one learn whilst sleeping? Can one solidify a memory & study for exams by listening to recordings while asleep?

Tags: memory, add-adhd, rapid-eye-movement-rem, concentration

I have ADD (not ADHD) and I am a PhD student so concentration is something that I consistently struggle with on a daily basis. Though I do take medications take medications for adult ADD, I am still struggling to remember everything for my candidacy exams.

I know you can't magically put a book under your pillow and let osmosis happen at night -- letting all the material leak into your brain. But can you solidify memory you've already studied by listening to recordings in your sleep? Does it work better in rapid-eye-movement or slow-wave-sleep?